# use setState as asynchronous function to save data

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, setstate

I'm trying to update a state in my react native component and i need to save this state to storage.
As setState is asyncronous i tried to pass a callback to setState like this :

```
 setData(
        {
          ...data,
          visible: true,
          color: Theme.COLORS.SUCCESS,
          message: 'Vous êtes connecter avec succès.',
          loading: false,
          person: response,
          token: response.data.token,
          refreshToken: response.data.refreshToken,
        },
        () => {
          console.log(token);
        },
      );
```

I got this warning : 
state updates from the usestate() and usereducer() hooks don't support the second callback argument..

How can i use the setState as a synchronous function ? and if it's not possible what's the alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But whenever you update the component's state, the component is going to be [eventually] re-rendered.

If your goal is to persist component state to storage, you could go with something like this:

```js
class SomeComp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(localstorage.getItem('somekey'))
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, _prevState, _snapshot) {
    localstorage.setItem('somekey', JSON.stringify(this.state))
  }
}
```

If personally use this hook for this same purpose:

```js
import ls from 'local-storage'
import { useState } from 'react'

// useState, but value is retrieved from local storage first time,
// and stored in local storage when updated
const useLSBackedState = (defaultValue, localStorageKey) => {
  const lsValue = ls.get(localStorageKey)
  const [value, doSetValue] = useState(
    lsValue === undefined ? defaultValue : lsValue
  )

  const setValue = value => {
    if (typeof value === 'function') {
      doSetValue(v => {
        const newValue = value(v)
        ls.set(localStorageKey, newValue)
        return newValue
      })
    } else {
      doSetValue(value)
      ls.set(localStorageKey, value)
    }
  }

  return [value, setValue]
}

// SomeComponent.js
const SomeComponent = _props => {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useLSBackedState(false, 'sidebarOpen')
  // ...
}
```

Comment: yes i think i have to use a react component instead of a function component